# My profile page shows two different reputation points at two places

Tags: support

This is strange. The following is the screenshot of my profile page -

[image: Profile page screenshot]

Here in one place it is showing the reputation as "637" and at another place it is showing reputation as "122".

What is the meaning of it?

Comment: The "122" is the reputation change since you last opened that pane

Comment: Try clicking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**637** is you total reputation.

While **122** is the change in your reputation since you last accessed the ***Reputation*** tab from the side pane.